# duplicates removal in database

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Suppose I have a table as :

[image]

It may have duplicate items in it.I know two ways in which this can be done.

- making a new table.
- adding distinct items from the first table to it.
- dropping the previous one.
- renaming it to the previous table.

Other way is in which we use indexes but since it requires memory for indexes I don't want to use that either.

Can someone suggest a simple way to delete duplicates from the table.

PS:I am using Postgres.

Comment: `delete` is the normal operation for removing duplicates.  The first is used on large tables.  I have no idea what "the other way" is.

Comment: More answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+delete+duplicates

Comment: Got it thanx :) @a_horse_with_no_name